# scrollToView() brings the element at the bottom. How to scroll element to the TOP

Tags: gwt, gwtp, scrollpane

I have many elements in a list (table). I want to auto scroll to one specific element.

Using **table.getRowElement(50).scrollIntoView();** scrolls the list to the  desired element but just enough to be visible in the scrollPanel i.e. at the bottom.

How to scroll element to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

able to achieve it by scrolling to bottom first and then to the desired element

```
scrollToTop(CellTable table, int position){
    if(table.getRowCount() > 0 && position >=0){
        //first - Scroll to bottom
        table.getRowElement(table.getRowCount() - 1).scrollIntoView();
        //second - scroll to element
        table.getRowElement(position).scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a slightly modified version of the scrollIntoView method in DOMImpl.class that leaves out the height.

```
public native void scrollIntoView(Element elem) /*-{
    var left = elem.offsetLeft, top = elem.offsetTop;
    var width = elem.offsetWidth, height = elem.offsetHeight;
    if (elem.parentNode != elem.offsetParent) {
        left -= elem.parentNode.offsetLeft;
        top -= elem.parentNode.offsetTop;
    }
    var cur = elem.parentNode;
    while (cur && (cur.nodeType == 1)) {
      if (left < cur.scrollLeft) {
        cur.scrollLeft = left;
      }
      if (left + width > cur.scrollLeft + cur.clientWidth) {
        cur.scrollLeft = (left + width) - cur.clientWidth;
      }
      if (top < cur.scrollTop) {
        cur.scrollTop = top;
      }
      if (top > cur.scrollTop) {
        cur.scrollTop = top;
      }
      var offsetLeft = cur.offsetLeft, offsetTop = cur.offsetTop;
      if (cur.parentNode != cur.offsetParent) {
        offsetLeft -= cur.parentNode.offsetLeft;
        offsetTop -= cur.parentNode.offsetTop;
      }
      left += offsetLeft - cur.scrollLeft;
      top += offsetTop - cur.scrollTop;
      cur = cur.parentNode;
    }
   }-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback but How to modify the DOMImpl its part of GWT library.